# how to fix My text slider moving correctly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel-5

I am running My text slider using  jquery and css in Laravel. My problem is when it is moving there are two moving positions. that means one moving round running correctly and then next round text comming with different position. (little bit height positions to first ) how can fix this

this is My css

```
#slider {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.slider-container { 
    background:#FFF; 
    width:845px; 
    height:150px; 
    padding:20px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

#slider img { 
    width:200px; 
    height:125px; 
    margin:0px; 
    display:inline-block  
}

#slider li {
    width:300px;


}
```

this is jquery

```
(function(a){a.fn.bxSlider=function(b){function Z(b,c,d,e){var f=[];var g=d;var h=false;if(e=="backward"){b=a.makeArray(b);b.reverse()}while(g>0){a.each(b,function(b,d){if(g>0){if(!h){if(b==c){h=true;f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{return false}})}return f}function Y(){var a=i.outerHeight()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function X(){var a=i.outerWidth()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function W(b,c){if(c=="left"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().left}else if(c=="top"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().top}return d}function V(){if(!b.infiniteLoop&&b.hideControlOnEnd){if(x==F){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-prev",h).show()}if(x==G){a(".bx-next",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-next",h).show()}}}function U(c,e,f,g){p=a('<a href="" class="bx-start"></a>');if(c=="text"){r=e}else{r='<img src="source/'+e+'" />'}if(f=="text"){s=g}else{s='<img src="source/'+g+'" />'}if(b.autoControlsSelector){a(b.autoControlsSelector).append(p)}else{h.append('<div class="bx-auto"></div>');a(".bx-auto",h).html(p)}p.click(function(){if(b.ticker){if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopTicker()}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startTicker()}}else{if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopShow(true)}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startShow(true)}}return false})}function T(){var c=a("img",g.eq(x)).attr("title");if(c!=""){if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html(c)}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html(c)}}else{if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html("Â ")}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html("Â ")}}}function S(c){var e=g.length;if(b.moveSlideQty>1){if(g.length%b.moveSlideQty!=0){e=Math.ceil(g.length/b.moveSlideQty)}else{e=g.length/b.moveSlideQty}}var f="";if(b.buildPager){for(var i=0;i<e;i++){f+=b.buildPager(i,g.eq(i*b.moveSlideQty))}}else if(c=="full"){for(var i=1;i<=e;i++){f+='<a href="" class="pager-link pager-'+i+'">'+i+"</a>"}}else if(c=="short"){f='<span class="bx-pager-current">'+(b.startingSlide+1)+"</span> "+b.pagerShortSeparator+' <span class="bx-pager-total">'+g.length+"</span>"}if(b.pagerSelector){a(b.pagerSelector).append(f);n=a(b.pagerSelector)}else{var j=a('<div class="bx-pager"></div>');j.append(f);if(b.pagerLocation=="top"){h.prepend(j)}else if(b.pagerLocation=="bottom"){h.append(j)}n=a(".bx-pager",h)}n.children().click(function(){if(b.pagerType=="full"){var a=n.children().index(this);if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a*=b.moveSlideQty}d.goToSlide(a)}return false})}function R(c,e,f,g){var i=a('<a href="" class="bx-next"></a>');var j=a('<a href="" class="bx-prev"></a>');if(c=="text"){i.html(e)}else{i.html('<img src="source/'+e+'" />')}if(f=="text"){j.html(g)}else{j.html('<img src="source/'+g+'" />')}if(b.prevSelector){a(b.prevSelector).append(j)}else{h.append(j)}if(b.nextSelector){a(b.nextSelector).append(i)}else{h.append(i)}i.click(function(){d.goToNextSlide();return false});j.click(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide();return false})}function Q(c){if(b.pagerType=="full"&&b.pager){a("a",n).removeClass(b.pagerActiveClass);a("a",n).eq(c).addClass(b.pagerActiveClass)}else if(b.pagerType=="short"&&b.pager){a(".bx-pager-current",n).html(x+1)}}function P(){g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(b.speed,0).css("zIndex",98);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99).fadeTo(b.speed,1,function(){E=false;if(jQuery.browser.msie){g.eq(x).get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}function O(){e.hover(function(){if(t){d.stopTicker(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startTicker(false)}})}function N(){h.find(".bx-window").hover(function(){if(t){d.stopShow(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startShow(false)}})}function M(){if(b.startImage!=""){startContent=b.startImage;startType="image"}else{startContent=b.startText;startType="text"}if(b.stopImage!=""){stopContent=b.stopImage;stopType="image"}else{stopContent=b.stopText;stopType="text"}U(startType,startContent,stopType,stopContent)}function L(a,c,d){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({left:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({left:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({top:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({top:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}}}function K(){if(b.auto){if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){x+=b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){x-=b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}}else{if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToNextSlide(false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide(false)},b.pause)}}}else if(b.ticker){b.tickerSpeed*=10;a(".pager",h).each(function(b){A+=a(this).width();B+=a(this).height()});if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="horizontal"){e.css("left","-"+(A+y)+"px")}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="vertical"){e.css("top","-"+(B+z)+"px")}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){C=parseInt(e.css("left"));L(C,A,b.tickerSpeed)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){D=parseInt(e.css("top"));L(D,B,b.tickerSpeed)}if(b.tickerHover){O()}}}function J(){if(b.nextImage!=""){nextContent=b.nextImage;nextType="image"}else{nextContent=b.nextText;nextType="text"}if(b.prevImage!=""){prevContent=b.prevImage;prevType="image"}else{prevContent=b.prevText;prevType="text"}R(nextType,nextContent,prevType,prevContent)}function I(){if(b.mode=="horizontal"||b.mode=="vertical"){var c=Z(g,0,b.moveSlideQty,"backward");a.each(c,function(b){e.prepend(a(this))});var d=g.length+b.moveSlideQty-1;var f=g.length-b.displaySlideQty;var h=d-f;var i=Z(g,0,h,"forward");if(b.infiniteLoop){a.each(i,function(b){e.append(a(this))})}}}function H(){I(b.startingSlide);if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+l+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:'+l+'px;"></div>').css({width:"999999px",position:"relative",left:"-"+y+"px"});e.children().css({width:j,"float":"left",listStyle:"none"});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="width:'+v+"px; height:"+m+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>').css({height:"999999px",position:"relative",top:"-"+z+"px"});e.children().css({listStyle:"none",height:w});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="fade"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="height:'+w+"px; width:"+v+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>');e.children().css({listStyle:"none",position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,zIndex:98});h=e.parent().parent();g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(0,0);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99)}if(b.captions&&b.captionsSelector==null){h.append('<div class="bx-captions"></div>')}}var c={mode:"horizontal",infiniteLoop:true,hideControlOnEnd:false,controls:true,speed:500,easing:"swing",pager:false,pagerSelector:null,pagerType:"full",pagerLocation:"bottom",pagerShortSeparator:"/",pagerActiveClass:"pager-active",nextText:"next",nextImage:"",nextSelector:null,prevText:"prev",prevImage:"",prevSelector:null,captions:false,captionsSelector:null,auto:false,autoDirection:"next",autoControls:false,autoControlsSelector:null,autoStart:true,autoHover:false,autoDelay:0,pause:3e3,startText:"start",startImage:"",stopText:"stop",stopImage:"",ticker:false,tickerSpeed:5e3,tickerDirection:"next",tickerHover:false,wrapperClass:"bx-wrapper",startingSlide:0,displaySlideQty:4,moveSlideQty:1,randomStart:false,onBeforeSlide:function(){},onAfterSlide:function(){},onLastSlide:function(){},onFirstSlide:function(){},onNextSlide:function(){},onPrevSlide:function(){},buildPager:null};var b=a.extend(c,b);var d=this;var e="";var f="";var g="";var h="";var i="";var j="";var k="";var l="";var m="";var n="";var o="";var p="";var q="";var r="";var s="";var t=true;var u=false;var v=0;var w=0;var x=0;var y=0;var z=0;var A=0;var B=0;var C=0;var D=0;var E=false;var F=0;var G=g.length-1;this.goToSlide=function(a,c){if(!E){E=true;x=a;b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}slide=a;if(slide==F){b.onFirstSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(slide==G){b.onLastSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.animate({left:"-"+W(slide,"left")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.animate({top:"-"+W(slide,"top")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}V();if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a=Math.floor(a/b.moveSlideQty)}Q(a);T()}};this.goToNextSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x<=G){V();b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}else{x-=b.moveSlideQty}}}else{if(!E){E=true;var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length;c=true}b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var f=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"-="+f+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var h=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"-="+h+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToPreviousSlide=function(c){if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){x=0;if(b.hideControlOnEnd){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}}V();b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}}else{if(!E){E=true;var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}f=true}b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var i=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"+="+i+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var j=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"+="+j+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToFirstSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(F,a)};this.goToLastSlide=function(){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(G,a)};this.getCurrentSlide=function(){return x};this.getSlideCount=function(){return g.length};this.stopShow=function(a){clearInterval(o);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startShow=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}K();if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}};this.stopTicker=function(a){e.stop();if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startTicker=function(a){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var c=parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=A+c+g.eq(0).width()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var c=-parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=c-g.eq(0).width()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/A;L(C,d,f)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var h=parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=B+h+g.eq(0).height()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var h=-parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=h-g.eq(0).height()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/B;L(D,d,f);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}}};this.initShow=function(){e=a(this);f=e.clone();g=e.children();h="";i=e.children(":first");j=i.width();v=0;k=i.outerWidth();w=0;l=X();m=Y();E=false;n="";x=0;y=0;z=0;o="";p="";q="";r="";s="";t=true;u=false;A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0;F=0;G=g.length-1;g.each(function(b){if(a(this).outerHeight()>w){w=a(this).outerHeight()}if(a(this).outerWidth()>v){v=a(this).outerWidth()}});if(b.randomStart){var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length);x=c;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+c);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+c)}else{x=b.startingSlide;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide)}H();if(b.pager&&!b.ticker){if(b.pagerType=="full"){S("full")}else if(b.pagerType=="short"){S("short")}}if(b.controls&&!b.ticker){J()}if(b.auto||b.ticker){if(b.autoControls){M()}if(b.autoStart){setTimeout(function(){d.startShow(true)},b.autoDelay)}else{d.stopShow(true)}if(b.autoHover&&!b.ticker){N()}}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}V();if(b.captions){T()}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))};this.destroyShow=function(){clearInterval(o);a(".bx-next, .bx-prev, .bx-pager, .bx-auto",h).remove();e.unwrap().unwrap().removeAttr("style");e.children().removeAttr("style").not(".pager").remove();g.removeClass("pager")};this.reloadShow=function(){d.destroyShow();d.initShow()};this.each(function(){if(a(this).children().length>0){d.initShow()}});return this};jQuery.fx.prototype.cur=function(){if(this.elem[this.prop]!=null&&(!this.elem.style||this.elem.style[this.prop]==null)){return this.elem[this.prop]}var a=parseFloat(jQuery.css(this.elem,this.prop));return a}})(jQuery)
```

blade view

```
<div class="slider-container">

    <ul id="slider">
    <li><a href="#"><p>Wealth Trust sign bond with </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Your capital has arise with </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>New Capital marcket </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>New Top Managers of </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Influence of </p></a></li>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using this tutorials  to run My test slider
http://wpandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/

can you give me solutions?

when I run images, then it is not this type problem....

Comment: You need to really swap the tags, `<a>` and `<p>`! And there's no `</ul>` but there's `</div>`!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of mistakes:

1. You need to really swap the tags, `<a>` and `<p>`!
2. And there's no `</ul>` but there's `</div>`!
3. No initialisation of `bxSlider`.
4. You didn't add the CSS too.

**Your working Snippet**

```js
(function(a){a.fn.bxSlider=function(b){function Z(b,c,d,e){var f=[];var g=d;var h=false;if(e=="backward"){b=a.makeArray(b);b.reverse()}while(g>0){a.each(b,function(b,d){if(g>0){if(!h){if(b==c){h=true;f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{return false}})}return f}function Y(){var a=i.outerHeight()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function X(){var a=i.outerWidth()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function W(b,c){if(c=="left"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().left}else if(c=="top"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().top}return d}function V(){if(!b.infiniteLoop&&b.hideControlOnEnd){if(x==F){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-prev",h).show()}if(x==G){a(".bx-next",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-next",h).show()}}}function U(c,e,f,g){p=a('<a href="" class="bx-start"></a>');if(c=="text"){r=e}else{r='<img src="source/'+e+'" />'}if(f=="text"){s=g}else{s='<img src="source/'+g+'" />'}if(b.autoControlsSelector){a(b.autoControlsSelector).append(p)}else{h.append('<div class="bx-auto"></div>');a(".bx-auto",h).html(p)}p.click(function(){if(b.ticker){if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopTicker()}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startTicker()}}else{if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopShow(true)}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startShow(true)}}return false})}function T(){var c=a("img",g.eq(x)).attr("title");if(c!=""){if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html(c)}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html(c)}}else{if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html("Â ")}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html("Â ")}}}function S(c){var e=g.length;if(b.moveSlideQty>1){if(g.length%b.moveSlideQty!=0){e=Math.ceil(g.length/b.moveSlideQty)}else{e=g.length/b.moveSlideQty}}var f="";if(b.buildPager){for(var i=0;i<e;i++){f+=b.buildPager(i,g.eq(i*b.moveSlideQty))}}else if(c=="full"){for(var i=1;i<=e;i++){f+='<a href="" class="pager-link pager-'+i+'">'+i+"</a>"}}else if(c=="short"){f='<span class="bx-pager-current">'+(b.startingSlide+1)+"</span> "+b.pagerShortSeparator+' <span class="bx-pager-total">'+g.length+"</span>"}if(b.pagerSelector){a(b.pagerSelector).append(f);n=a(b.pagerSelector)}else{var j=a('<div class="bx-pager"></div>');j.append(f);if(b.pagerLocation=="top"){h.prepend(j)}else if(b.pagerLocation=="bottom"){h.append(j)}n=a(".bx-pager",h)}n.children().click(function(){if(b.pagerType=="full"){var a=n.children().index(this);if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a*=b.moveSlideQty}d.goToSlide(a)}return false})}function R(c,e,f,g){var i=a('<a href="" class="bx-next"></a>');var j=a('<a href="" class="bx-prev"></a>');if(c=="text"){i.html(e)}else{i.html('<img src="source/'+e+'" />')}if(f=="text"){j.html(g)}else{j.html('<img src="source/'+g+'" />')}if(b.prevSelector){a(b.prevSelector).append(j)}else{h.append(j)}if(b.nextSelector){a(b.nextSelector).append(i)}else{h.append(i)}i.click(function(){d.goToNextSlide();return false});j.click(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide();return false})}function Q(c){if(b.pagerType=="full"&&b.pager){a("a",n).removeClass(b.pagerActiveClass);a("a",n).eq(c).addClass(b.pagerActiveClass)}else if(b.pagerType=="short"&&b.pager){a(".bx-pager-current",n).html(x+1)}}function P(){g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(b.speed,0).css("zIndex",98);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99).fadeTo(b.speed,1,function(){E=false;if(jQuery.browser.msie){g.eq(x).get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}function O(){e.hover(function(){if(t){d.stopTicker(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startTicker(false)}})}function N(){h.find(".bx-window").hover(function(){if(t){d.stopShow(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startShow(false)}})}function M(){if(b.startImage!=""){startContent=b.startImage;startType="image"}else{startContent=b.startText;startType="text"}if(b.stopImage!=""){stopContent=b.stopImage;stopType="image"}else{stopContent=b.stopText;stopType="text"}U(startType,startContent,stopType,stopContent)}function L(a,c,d){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({left:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({left:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({top:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({top:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}}}function K(){if(b.auto){if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){x+=b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){x-=b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}}else{if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToNextSlide(false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide(false)},b.pause)}}}else if(b.ticker){b.tickerSpeed*=10;a(".pager",h).each(function(b){A+=a(this).width();B+=a(this).height()});if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="horizontal"){e.css("left","-"+(A+y)+"px")}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="vertical"){e.css("top","-"+(B+z)+"px")}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){C=parseInt(e.css("left"));L(C,A,b.tickerSpeed)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){D=parseInt(e.css("top"));L(D,B,b.tickerSpeed)}if(b.tickerHover){O()}}}function J(){if(b.nextImage!=""){nextContent=b.nextImage;nextType="image"}else{nextContent=b.nextText;nextType="text"}if(b.prevImage!=""){prevContent=b.prevImage;prevType="image"}else{prevContent=b.prevText;prevType="text"}R(nextType,nextContent,prevType,prevContent)}function I(){if(b.mode=="horizontal"||b.mode=="vertical"){var c=Z(g,0,b.moveSlideQty,"backward");a.each(c,function(b){e.prepend(a(this))});var d=g.length+b.moveSlideQty-1;var f=g.length-b.displaySlideQty;var h=d-f;var i=Z(g,0,h,"forward");if(b.infiniteLoop){a.each(i,function(b){e.append(a(this))})}}}function H(){I(b.startingSlide);if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+l+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:'+l+'px;"></div>').css({width:"999999px",position:"relative",left:"-"+y+"px"});e.children().css({width:j,"float":"left",listStyle:"none"});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="width:'+v+"px; height:"+m+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>').css({height:"999999px",position:"relative",top:"-"+z+"px"});e.children().css({listStyle:"none",height:w});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="fade"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="height:'+w+"px; width:"+v+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>');e.children().css({listStyle:"none",position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,zIndex:98});h=e.parent().parent();g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(0,0);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99)}if(b.captions&&b.captionsSelector==null){h.append('<div class="bx-captions"></div>')}}var c={mode:"horizontal",infiniteLoop:true,hideControlOnEnd:false,controls:true,speed:500,easing:"swing",pager:false,pagerSelector:null,pagerType:"full",pagerLocation:"bottom",pagerShortSeparator:"/",pagerActiveClass:"pager-active",nextText:"next",nextImage:"",nextSelector:null,prevText:"prev",prevImage:"",prevSelector:null,captions:false,captionsSelector:null,auto:false,autoDirection:"next",autoControls:false,autoControlsSelector:null,autoStart:true,autoHover:false,autoDelay:0,pause:3e3,startText:"start",startImage:"",stopText:"stop",stopImage:"",ticker:false,tickerSpeed:5e3,tickerDirection:"next",tickerHover:false,wrapperClass:"bx-wrapper",startingSlide:0,displaySlideQty:4,moveSlideQty:1,randomStart:false,onBeforeSlide:function(){},onAfterSlide:function(){},onLastSlide:function(){},onFirstSlide:function(){},onNextSlide:function(){},onPrevSlide:function(){},buildPager:null};var b=a.extend(c,b);var d=this;var e="";var f="";var g="";var h="";var i="";var j="";var k="";var l="";var m="";var n="";var o="";var p="";var q="";var r="";var s="";var t=true;var u=false;var v=0;var w=0;var x=0;var y=0;var z=0;var A=0;var B=0;var C=0;var D=0;var E=false;var F=0;var G=g.length-1;this.goToSlide=function(a,c){if(!E){E=true;x=a;b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}slide=a;if(slide==F){b.onFirstSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(slide==G){b.onLastSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.animate({left:"-"+W(slide,"left")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.animate({top:"-"+W(slide,"top")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}V();if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a=Math.floor(a/b.moveSlideQty)}Q(a);T()}};this.goToNextSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x<=G){V();b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}else{x-=b.moveSlideQty}}}else{if(!E){E=true;var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length;c=true}b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var f=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"-="+f+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var h=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"-="+h+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToPreviousSlide=function(c){if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){x=0;if(b.hideControlOnEnd){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}}V();b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}}else{if(!E){E=true;var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}f=true}b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var i=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"+="+i+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var j=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"+="+j+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToFirstSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(F,a)};this.goToLastSlide=function(){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(G,a)};this.getCurrentSlide=function(){return x};this.getSlideCount=function(){return g.length};this.stopShow=function(a){clearInterval(o);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startShow=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}K();if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}};this.stopTicker=function(a){e.stop();if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startTicker=function(a){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var c=parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=A+c+g.eq(0).width()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var c=-parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=c-g.eq(0).width()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/A;L(C,d,f)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var h=parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=B+h+g.eq(0).height()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var h=-parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=h-g.eq(0).height()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/B;L(D,d,f);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}}};this.initShow=function(){e=a(this);f=e.clone();g=e.children();h="";i=e.children(":first");j=i.width();v=0;k=i.outerWidth();w=0;l=X();m=Y();E=false;n="";x=0;y=0;z=0;o="";p="";q="";r="";s="";t=true;u=false;A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0;F=0;G=g.length-1;g.each(function(b){if(a(this).outerHeight()>w){w=a(this).outerHeight()}if(a(this).outerWidth()>v){v=a(this).outerWidth()}});if(b.randomStart){var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length);x=c;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+c);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+c)}else{x=b.startingSlide;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide)}H();if(b.pager&&!b.ticker){if(b.pagerType=="full"){S("full")}else if(b.pagerType=="short"){S("short")}}if(b.controls&&!b.ticker){J()}if(b.auto||b.ticker){if(b.autoControls){M()}if(b.autoStart){setTimeout(function(){d.startShow(true)},b.autoDelay)}else{d.stopShow(true)}if(b.autoHover&&!b.ticker){N()}}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}V();if(b.captions){T()}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))};this.destroyShow=function(){clearInterval(o);a(".bx-next, .bx-prev, .bx-pager, .bx-auto",h).remove();e.unwrap().unwrap().removeAttr("style");e.children().removeAttr("style").not(".pager").remove();g.removeClass("pager")};this.reloadShow=function(){d.destroyShow();d.initShow()};this.each(function(){if(a(this).children().length>0){d.initShow()}});return this};jQuery.fx.prototype.cur=function(){if(this.elem[this.prop]!=null&&(!this.elem.style||this.elem.style[this.prop]==null)){return this.elem[this.prop]}var a=parseFloat(jQuery.css(this.elem,this.prop));return a}})(jQuery)
$(function () {
  $("#slider").bxSlider({
    ticker: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <ul id="slider">
    <li><p><a href="#">Wealth Trust sign bond with </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">Your capital has arise with </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">New Capital marcket </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">New Top Managers of </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">Influence of </a></p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The right one should have the CSS and JS intact. **Not inline**.

**Right Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#slider").bxSlider({
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 170,
    slideMargin: 10,
    ticker: true,
    speed: 6000
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <ul id="slider">
    <li><p><a href="#">Wealth Trust sign bond with </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">Your capital has arise with </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">New Capital marcket </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">New Top Managers of </a></p></li>
    <li><p><a href="#">Influence of </a></p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```